# grid-template-columns that bleed to the edge but are clamped in size

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a grid with a **variable and unknown amount of cells** such that:

- The size of each cell is between MINIMUM and MAXIMUM size (lets say 200px and 500px) AND
- The cells always expand all the way to edge of the container

https://codesandbox.io/s/grid-auto-fit-jqp7w

If you do

```
    gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr))`,
```

the cells will always fill up to the edge of the container correctly, but if you only have one cell, it can potentially be very large.

[image]

If you do

```
  gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 500px))`,
```

the grid cells will wrap rather than decrease their size to fit

[image]

Comment: Clarification: Wondering if this is possible to do in CSS only. One could probably resolve this with Javascript.

Comment: *The cells always expand all the way to edge of the container* This is exactly what your first example does. Please elaborate on the desired result.

Comment: auto-fill instead of auto-fit

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a way to achieve what you want using fixed width in `minmax`, like 200px and 500px. But a close option is to use `auto-fill`. It keeps responsiveness but does not allow a single child to take the full width of its parent when the screen is large.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  gap: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.cell {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.single {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="single cell">single cell</div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
  <div class="cell">cell</div>
</div>
```